# break array into parts and then insert it into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have something like this

```
621 Aug 20, 2014 00:04:52.574230000 362 10.0.0.16   184.180.124.176 33  51821   80  1   297 1   296 297 1   GET HTTP/1.1 http://mesu.apple.com/assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate.xml /assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate.xml   MobileAsset/1.1 mesu.apple.com
```

This is my data that I want to insert into mySql database. This data is in a variable `array[0]` I have many elements as this in my array. I have a table strucature for my data. like The first field is id. second is date. How can I insert this row into mysql database. Exploding on the basis of space is also exploding my date. is there any way to do this.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string function

Comment: If there's a pattern to it, you can use a regular expression to extract the parts into an array. If not, I don't know how you expect the program to figure out where the element boundaries are.

Comment: @saurav What does that have to do with splitting up the string into different fields?

Comment: @Barmar he can use explode to break string or reg exp

Comment: @Barmar sir , there are spaces in between but then it is also manipulating the date

Comment: What should he use as the delimiter with `explode`? Like he said in the question, if he uses space as the delimiter, it will break the date into separate fields.

Comment: This is a webserver log line, isn't it? There are lots of existing tools for processing webserver logs, have you searched for them?

Comment: @Barmar, Yes sir it is a log file. I am trying to find an alternative for the time being because squid is not working. I know there are many tools.

Comment: Use a regular expression with capture groups to get an array that corresponds to how you want to group the fields in the log.

Comment: sir  i have never used regular exp. can u explain a bit more